# Removing Duplicates Issue

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to remove duplicates of rows with this code:

```
    Sub removeDuplicates()
'
' Macro7 Macro

'Workbooks("Tester.xlsm").Worksheets(1).Range("A1", Range("F1").End(xlDown)).removeDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2), Header:=xlYes
Set Rng = Range("A1", Range("F1").End(xlDown))
    Workbooks("Tester").Worksheets(1).Rng.removeDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2), Header:=xlYes

End Sub
```

However, it gives me a runtime 1004 error, what am I doing wrong? Is there a solution to this?
Btw the commented code does not work also, it gives back the same error message

Comment: Instead do `Set Rng = Workbooks("Tester").Worksheets(1).Range("A1", Workbooks("Tester").Worksheets(1).Range("F1").End(xlDown))`, then just`Rng.removeDuplicates ...`

Comment: You have to use `Workbooks("Tester.xlsm")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Worksheet` class doesn't provide the `Rng` property. It seems you are trying to re-use the variable `Rng` defined in the code, but it is not yet assigned until the line is finished running. Use the [Worksheet.Range](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Worksheet.Range) property instead:

```
Set Rng = Workbooks("Tester").Worksheets(1).Range("A1", Workbooks("Tester").Worksheets(1).Range("F1").End(xlDown))
Rng.removeDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2), Header:=xlYes
```